# Android, Phone playing notification sounds even when on silent? Should I be checking for silent mode?

Tags: android

I was very surprised to find in the app I am currently programming that when I make it play a notification sound, it plays regardless of whether the phone has been set to silent or not!

Surely the phones silent mode should be an overriding feature or am I meant to be checking?
I had a quick look at the documentation but did not see anything saying this? Am I missing something?

This is my notification code:

```
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        v.vibrate(300);

        Uri alert = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, alert);

        final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0) {
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
            mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }
```

Thanks for any feedback here!

Bex

Comment: I have the same issue, however I am playing a regular sound file ( it is not an alarm ). Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure about the documentation you checked, but on Nexus One below Silent mode checkbox it clearly says:

```
Silence all sounds except media & alarms.
```

In your example you are playing alarm (not notification), so it is correct.

Comment: Oh I didn't realise this! Teach me for copying code! Also didn't realise alarms would still go off either though! :)

Comment: OK, it is always easier for someone "outside" to discover your issue by short view. Regards.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the testing results it seems that you're the one that needs to check it:

```
if (audioManager.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL) {
    // Play the sound
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) set StandupReciver.java

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class StandupReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"inside Recevier",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        NotificationManager myManager=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mynoti=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    // FOR SILENT MODE
    AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    // For Normal mode
    int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    int maxVolume = audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float percent = 2.0f;
    int seventyVolume = (int) (maxVolume*percent);
    audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, seventyVolume, 0);
    audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
    audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);


    mynoti.setContentTitle("Stand up Notification");
    mynoti.setContentText("you need to stand up");
    mynoti.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });
    mynoti.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
    mynoti.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_btn_speak_now);



    Intent il=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pd= PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,il,0);
    mynoti.setContentIntent(pd);
    mynoti.setAutoCancel(true);
    myManager.notify(1,mynoti.build());
}}
```

2) AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<receiver
        android:name=".StandupReciver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.xyz.myown.recevier.Message"/>
            <category  android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

3)MainActivity.java

start method

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction("com.xyz.myown.recevier.Message");
                i.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
                PendingIntent pd = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 10, pd);
```

stop method

```
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Stop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i=new Intent();
            i.setAction("com.xyz.myown.recevier.Message");
            i.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
            PendingIntent pd= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0,i,0);
            alarmManager.cancel(pd);
```

Comment: I think, its not good approache. As we don't know When to set currentVolume of audio manager again.